# The Creation of Swap Space in Partition #9 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) Failed

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, swap

I am trying ubuntu 13.04 from **sandisk cruzer blade**.

I want to install it .
I created a partition of 25 GB. I formatted to ex4-or something like that and mounted it to- `/`

But I am reciving -

```
The creation of swap space in partition #9 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) failed.
```

See picture-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you made a partition of 25 GB to install Ubuntu.If you want to have a swap then you gonna need two partitions.One for swap and one for root(/).Mount the smaller,usually 4 Gb on `linux-swap` and the rest on root(`/`).